# URL grammar rules

Tags: url, syntax

I made a pastebin site where each entry gets a random string. For example

```
example.com/ds34
example.com/sdf-2zA
example.com/234+_2
```

My question is, what is the grammar rule for these strings?
Can that start with anything? which characters are/aren't allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See in [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) and [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html). In short - any ASCII symbol excluding reserved `! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $, / ? % # [ ]`. Other symbols can be percent-encoded.

Comment: There are the symbols that not allowed? Some of the strings generated contains '+' and seem to work fine, though.